# What is the FIELDS TERMINATED BY field for when importing XLS file to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel

My xls file's data,

```
id    |   name       |  address
----------------------------------
01    |   mani       |   us
02    |   saro       |  india
```

I am trying to export `myexceldata.xls` into a MySql's table `CheckExcel` using below code

```
package Default;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class automateImport
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DBase db = new DBase();
        Connection conn = db.connect(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RTS","root","");
//        db.importData(conn,args[0]);
        db.importData(conn, "/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/DBToMysql.xls");
    }

}

class DBase
{
    public DBase()
    {
    }

    public Connection connect(String db_connect_str, 
  String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
        Connection conn;
        try 
        {
            Class.forName(  
    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_str, 
    db_userid, db_password);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            conn = null;
        }

        return conn;    
    }

    public void importData(Connection conn,String filename)
    {
        Statement stmt;
        String query;

        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String filename1 ="/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/DBToMysql.xls";
            String tablename ="CheckExcel";


           query ="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"" + filename1 + "\" INTO TABLE " + tablename + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("success");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stmt = null;
        }
    }
};
```

But my result is,

[image]

I know that I am doing mistake in `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, but even when I tried with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'` or `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'`, it's no use!

Can please someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

LOAD DATA INFILE is for importing CSV data (or to be more precise, data in text files). Excel files are NOT CSV (not text).

Comment: so i cant export .xls to mysql?

Comment: Yes, export your .xls into .csv first, and then try again with that .csv file.

Comment: @StorymasterQ yes i am getting result correct when i do with .csv file.but i if do directly .xls to mysql means then i can save my time instead of change to cvs file.

Comment: @StorymasterQ and one more error that my heading(id,name,address) also included every time uploading to table.how to solve this?

Comment: As @Mchl said, `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is for importing CSV data. If you want to import XLS file directly, you should use something else.